# Peculiarities of non-Abelian gauge groups: self-coupling and topology

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, research-level, topology, instantons

There are two striking aspects of [non-Abelian gauge groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-abelian_group) (compared to their [Abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) cousins):

(1) The pure gauge parts of non-Abelian Lagrangians contain [self-interaction terms](https://www.nikhef.nl/~t45/ftip/Ch12.pdf) that are trilinear and quadrilinear in the gauge fields.

(2) Non-Abelian gauge groups have topologically non-trivial field configurations (e.g. [instantons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton)).

Are these two aspects of non-Abelian gauge groups completely unrelated or is there an intuitive connection between (1) and (2)?

For example, ['t Hooft showed](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.14.3432) that fermionic zero modes in the instanton background lead to a non-perturbative multi-fermion interaction in the low energy effective action - can that somehow be related to the self-interaction in the pure gauge parts?

Comment: Your 't Hooft reference is only an erratum. Can you give the full reference?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to say that they're unrelated.

Abelian gauge groups can exhibit instantons and other non-trivial topological behavior.   Likewise there's Abelian chern-Simons theory, where the natural Lagrangian has a cubic interaction.